# Italic fonts for plots like those appear in scientific papers

Tags: plotting, fonts, plot-themes

Suppose we want to draw the following plot:

```
DensityPlot[ Sin[ x y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, MaxRecursion -> 8,
PlotRange -> All, 
ColorFunction -> (Hue[Rescale[#, {0, 1}, {.7, 0}]] &), 
FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(g\)]\)", 
FontSlant -> Italic, FontSize -> 24], 
Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(g\)]\)", FontSlant -> Italic, 
FontSize -> 24]}, 
LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, FontSize -> 16, FontFamily -> Times}, 
Frame ->  True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], 
BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16, FontFamily -> Times},
PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
]
```

As you see in the following figure, the labels of the plot are italic, but not the kind we need in scientific papers.

[image]

What I need is this:

[image]

Is there any way to get this kind of "italic" font? I know that `MaTex` may work, but I'm looking for an easier way. I tried installing `MaTex`, but never succeeded.

Comment: Are you looking for a font recommendation?

Comment: you may use `$FontFamilies` to see the fonts available on your system and try one that looks like what you need by replacing `FontFamily -> Times` with the new font. For example, on my mac there's a font "Calisto MT" that may fit, via `FontFamily -> "Calisto MT"`

Comment: I would use `Subscript[x, g]` instead of the inscrutable `"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(g\)]\)"`. If `p` is your plot, what does `Options[p]` return?

Comment: MaTeX is really powerful once you have installed it, and there is a paclet installer. See https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX/

Comment: Perhaps `FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"`

Comment: You must have set a non-default option for Graphics or DensityPlot, because I get the desired fonts when I execute your code. This is why I asked you to tell us what `Options[plot]` returns. At any rate, fonts are specified using strings, not symbols. If you change `Times` to `"Times"` I expect that you will get the font you want.

Comment: Option[plot] yields {}. I used "Times", but it did not work. Anyway, I tried "Aparajita" font, which sounds like Times and works well.

Answer (score 7):

Joining the [answer by José](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/170278/22013) and a [comment by egwene](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170276/italic-fonts-for-plots-like-those-appear-in-scientific-papers#comment447653_170276):

```
{#, Style[
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(g\)]\)  \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\),   \(g\)]\)",
     FontSlant -> Italic, FontFamily -> #, 32]} & /@ $FontFamilies // Grid
```

gives a list in which many fonts provide outputs similar to what is desired.

`$FontFamilies // Length` yields `285`, so for the sake of sanity only first 40 fonts are displayed in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Good list (+1)...

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you are looking for the fontname "Euclid". However, be advised that you must have this font installed in your system:

```
Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(g\)]\)  \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \
      \(g\)]\)", FontSlant -> Italic, FontFamily -> "Euclid", 32]
```

[image]

You should be also be aware about the font recommended for the plots in the journal you want to publish your paper (often, Times or Arial).

```
Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(g\)]\)  \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(P\), \
      \(g\)]\)", FontSlant -> Italic, FontFamily -> "Times", 32]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried elucid as you recommended, but it did not work. I had installed that on my system.

Comment: Sounds bizarre. Anyway, and after seeing your font request in detail in your second fig, I would bet on "Times" as the font you are looking for. You can also take a look at the answer by @corey979